# From a float to an integer

Tags: c, types, integer

Given this code that my professor gave us in an exam which means we cannot modify the code nor use function from other libraries (except stdio.h):

```
float x;

(suppose x NOT having an integer part)
while (CONDITION){
    x = x*10
}
```

I have to find the condition **that makes sure that x has no valid number to the right of decimal point** not giving attention to the problems of precision of a float number (After the decimal point we have to have only zeros). I tried this condition:

```
while ((fmod((x*10),10))){
    X = X*10
}
printf(" %f ",x);
```

example:

```
INPUT x=0.456; --------> OUTPUT: 456.000
INPUT X=0.4567;--------> OUTPUT; 4567.000
It is important to be sure that after the decimal point we don't have any        
significant number
```

But I had to include math.h library BUT my professor doesn't allow us to use it in this specific case (I'm not even allowed to use (long) since we never seen it in class).

So what is the condition that solve the problem properly without this library?

Comment: This generally doesn't make sense since floating point can't accurately represent most numbers and will have as many decimal digits as it's  total precision.

Comment: You could study [`float` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985t) and make some tests on internal bits

Comment: _I'm not even allowed to use (long) since we never seen it in class_ This does not make sense.... cast is the easiest way to do so, although, as @2501 already wrote, is not accurate.

Comment: I just made a research on Casting method and I agree with you it makes the solution easy even though in class we never wrote something like: int num;
float real;

real = 47.19;
num = (int)real; // 47 That's why I don't find other solutions

Comment: Probably your professor should specify you constrains for this test and what kind of precision he/she would expect. If your professor is not aware of precision problems, you should start thinking about change the school/class... ;)

Comment: Actually my professor talked about the precision problems. Don't worry he is a great professor ahah

Comment: Please modify your question and give an clear example of different inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is fuzziness ("not giving attention to the problems of precision of a float number") in the question, yet I think a sought answer is below, assign `x` to an integer type until `x` no longer has a fractional part.

Success of this method depends on `INT_MIN <= x <= INT_MAX`.  This is expected when the number of bits in the significant of `float` does not exceed the value bits of `int`.  Although this is common, it is not specified by C.  As an alternative, code could with a wider integer type like `long long` with a far less chance of the range restriction issue.

Given the rounding introduced with `*10`, this method is *not* a good foundation of `float` to text conversion.

```
float Dipok(float x) {
  int i;
  while ((i=x) != x) {
      x = x*10;
  }
  return x;
}

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

void Dipok_test(float x) {
  // suppose x NOT having an integer part
  assert(x > -1.0 && x < 1.0);
  float y = Dipok(x);
  printf("x:%.*f y:%.f\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, x, y);
}

int main(void) {
  Dipok_test(0.456);
  Dipok_test(0.4567);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
x:0.456000000 y:456
x:0.456699997 y:4567
```

Comment: ... and `Dipok_test(0.001);` yields `x:0.001000 y:10000001` on my machine.

Comment: @undur_gongor  A typical `float` using [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format with `float x = 0.001` will set `x` to the exact value of `0.001000000047497451305389404296875`.  It is this value that `Dipok(float x)` receives.  Given that OP specified "not giving attention to the problems of precision of a float number", the answer of `10000001` is OK.  OP is certainly using this as a base for other applications and will use the loop count of `while ((i=x) != x)` to further process `100`, `10000001` or whatever.

Comment: While this is formally correct, I feel it's a bit far-fetched. Would be curious to see if OP is happy with the result in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out here previously:Due to the accuracy of floats this is not really possible but I think your Prof wants to get something like

```
while (x  - (int)x != 0 )
```

or

```
while (x  - (int)x >= 0.00000001 )
```

You can get rid of the zeroes by using the g modifier instead of f:

```
printf(" %g \n",x);
```

Comment: This will fail if the actual float value is slightly smaller than the intended one.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by [2501](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082723/2501), this is just not possible.

Floats are not accurate. Depending on your platform, the float value for 0.001 is represented as something like 0.0010000001 in fact.

What would you expect the code to calculate: 10000001 or 1?

Any solution will work for some values only.

Comment: Typical `float` have 6+ digits of _relative_ decimal accuracy.  Their values are exact.  The issue is that many _operations_ on `floats` incur rounding such as the assignment of `float x = 0.001;`.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer to my exam question please if I say something wrong correct me!

It is not possible to find a proper condition that makes sure that there are no valid number after the decimal point. For example : We want to know the result of 0.4*20 which is 8.000 BUT due to imprecision problems the output will be different:

```
f=0.4;
for(i=1;i<20;i++)
   f=f+0.4;
printf("The number f=0.4*20 is ");
if(f!=8.0) {printf(" not ");}
printf(" %f ",8.0);
printf("The real answer is f=0.4*20= %f",f);
```

Our OUTPUT will be:

```
The number f=0.4*20 is not 8.000000 

The real answer is f=0.4*20= 8.000001
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to use function from other libraries except stdio.h, I used only printf just to show that float numbers are not precise.